# Regression with Python (nympy/pandas)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have the following beginning:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

# You can use np.random.seed(0)
#n = 15
#x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
#y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10 function to help you visualize the dataset by
# plotting a scatterplot of the data points
# in the training and test sets.
def part1_scatter():
    %matplotlib notebook
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, label='training data')
    plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, label='test data')
    plt.legend(loc=4);
```

And based on it I have this question:

Write a function that fits a polynomial LinearRegression model on the training data X_train for degrees 1, 3, 6, and 9. (Use PolynomialFeatures in sklearn.preprocessing to create the polynomial features and then fit a linear regression model) For each model, find 100 predicted values over the interval x = 0 to 10 (e.g. np.linspace(0,10,100)) and store this in a numpy array. The first row of this array should correspond to the output from the model trained on degree 1, the second row degree 3, the third row degree 6, and the fourth row degree 9.

This function should return a numpy array with shape (4, 100)

Here is my code:

```
def answer_one():
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
    result = np.numbers((4, 100))
    for i, degree in enumerate([1, 3, 6, 9]):
        poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
        X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(11,1))
        linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, y_train)
        y = linreg.predict(poly.fit_transform(np.linspace(0,10,100).reshape(100,1)))
        result[i, :] = y
    return result
```

And the code for the plot:

```
def plot_one(degree_predictions):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    plt.plot(X_train, y_train, 'o', label='training data', markersize=10)
    plt.plot(X_test, y_test, 'o', label='test data', markersize=10)
    for i,degree in enumerate([1,3,6,9]):
        plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,100), degree_predictions[i], alpha=0.8, lw=2, label='degree={}'.format(degree))
    plt.ylim(-1,2.5)
    plt.legend(loc=4)
```

But the following errors appears:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
~/grader/assignment2_student_solution.py in
<module>()        7 import numpy as np        8
import pandas as pd  ----> 9 import
matplotlib.pyplot as plt       10 from
sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
11     /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
113       114 from matplotlib.backends import
pylab_setup  --> 115 _backend_mod,
new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show =
pylab_setup()      116       117 _IP_REGISTERED =
None    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py in
pylab_setup()       30     # imports. 0 means only
perform absolute imports.       31     backend_mod
= __import__(backend_name,  ---> 32
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)       33
34     # Things we pull in from all backends
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py in
<module>()       14        15 from .backend_agg
import FigureCanvasAgg  ---> 16 from .backend_qt5
import QtCore       17 from .backend_qt5 import
QtGui       18 from .backend_qt5 import
FigureManagerQT    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py in
<module>()       24        25 from
matplotlib.widgets import SubplotTool  ---> 26
import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions
as figureoptions       27        28 from
.qt_compat import (QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,
_getSaveFileName,
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/
backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py in <module>()
18 import matplotlib       19 from matplotlib
import cm, markers, colors as mcolors  ---> 20
import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as
formlayout       21 from
matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui
22     /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matp
lotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py in
<module>()       54        55 from matplotlib
import colors as mcolors  ---> 56 from
matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui,
QtWidgets, QtCore       57        58
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py in
<module>()      126     if QT_API == QT_API_PYQT5:
127         try:  --> 128             from PyQt5
import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets      129
_getSaveFileName =
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName      130
except ImportError:    ImportError: libGL.so.1:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory
```

Where could be the problem?

Comment: This is not a problem with regression; it's a problem in matplotlib. See this for info & some potential solutions: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/49 (FYI: I found that by putting the last line of your error message into a search engine)

Comment: Since Jupyter Textbook in Coursera is set to verstion 1.2, I don't know what I can do..

Comment: What happens when you install mesa's libgl?